# Java Multidimensional array - how to create multi-dimensional array from regular array elements

Tags: java

I have to write a code that will take each element of the one-dimensional array and based on the value of that element create multidimensional array. Every array in the multi-dimensional array will have the column numbers equal to the number on that index in one-dimensional array, and the result should be stored in multi-dimensional array resArray. This is the example of what I am looking for:
this is a start array: `int[] arrayStart = new int[]{2, 5, 4, 2, 6, 3};`
the result should be:
`int[][] resArray = new int[][]{{2 ,2},{5, 5, 5 , 5, 5}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {2, 2}, {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}, {3, 3, 3}};`

I built this so far, but the result is not what I am looking for.

```
int[] arrayStart = new int[]{2, 5, 4, 2, 6, 3};
    int[][] extendedArray;
    int lengthArray = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayStart.length; i++) {
        extendedArray = new int[arrayStart.length][arrayStart[i]];
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayStart[i]; j++) {
            lengthArray  = arrayStart[i];
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < lengthArray; x++) {
            extendedArray[i][x] = lengthArray;
        }
            for (int k = 0; k < arrayStart.length; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < extendedArray[k].length; l++) {
                    System.out.print(extendedArray[k][l] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    }
```

---

And this is a result I receive when I try to print elements from multi-dimensional array at the end. Just need to figure out how to avoid saving arrays with "0's", and only save ones that have a elements that I am looking for.

```
2   2   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   
5   5   5   5   5   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
4   4   4   4   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0   
2   2   
0   0   
0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   
6   6   6   6   6   6   
0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0   
3   3   3
```

Comment: `This is the example of what I am looking for: this is a start array: int[] arrayStart = new int[]{2, 5, 4, 2, 6, 3}; the result should be: int[][] resArray = new int[][]{{2 ,2},{5, 5, 5 , 5, 5}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {2, 2}, {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}, {3, 3, 3}};`

Comment: Its is already in the question

Comment: @MaciejNiedźwiedź you didn't need to delete your answer. Nobody has really explained why their answers work. For example, how did you know the initial length of resArray?

Comment: @matt i deleted it as this code could use some improvments leading to answer already provided, i didn't see any value in duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Be Simple.** You have a pretty clear description. Just do it.

```java
public static int[][] createLengthArray(int... arr) {
    // here no need to set row's length
    int[][] res = new int[arr.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int length = arr[i];
        // 2D array is an 1D array where each element is 1D array
        res[i] = new int[length];
        // standard way to fill an empty array
        Arrays.fill(res[i], length);
    }

    return res;
}
```

---

**P.S.** Look at your code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arrayStart.length; i++) {
    extendedArray = new int[arrayStart.length][arrayStart[i]];
    //...
}
```

Here you create a new 2D array `extendedArray` on each iteration. That's why you have so many `0s` in the output. All you need is to create a result array only once and then fill it in the loop.

Comment: Maybe you should explain the differences because they're definitely missing some of these concepts.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. 
Thanks Oleg!